# How can I adjust 'the time' in python with module Re

Tags: python, regex, try-except

this is a funny question.
I try to find out the right time in some phrases.
I use `try-except` module and `re` module
but there is something wrong in my code that can't deal with some tough phrase

As is depicted belong, I input the rediculous time **1997-25-52** or **1996-42-120**
it still can output an answer.

```py
def regular_time(time):
    """
    部分电影日期带有国家, 例如：'1994-09-10(加拿大)'
    正则提取日期
    """
    import re
    pattern = '^(([1-2]\d{3})-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))'
    try:
        matches = re.match(pattern, time, flags=0).group()
        return matches
    except Exception as e:
        try:
              pattern = '^(([1-2]\d{3})-(0[1-9]|1[0-2]))'
              matches = re.match(pattern, time, flags=0).group()+'-01'
              return matches
        except:
           try:
              pattern = '^(([1-2]\d{3}))'
              matches = re.match(pattern, time, flags=0).group() + '-01-01'
              return matches
           except:
              print('errors')
time='1996-12-58'
regular_time(time)
```

How can I deal with this problem? Many thanks if you could do me a favor

Comment: `try` - `except` is not a module.

Comment: Also a bare `except` isn't worth good as per [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: Default date from invalid `datestring`

Using `datetime` handles also **leap years**!

- [datetime.datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)
- [datetime.date.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

For example:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

def regular_time(time):
    _t = time.split('-')
    # allways 3 itmes
    while len(_t) < 3:
        _t.append('01')

    # year month and day ranges
    ymd = [(range(1900, 2099), '1900'), 
           (range(1, 13), '01'),
           (range(1, 32), '01')
          ]

    # validate ranges
    for n in range(3):
        if not int(_t[n]) in ymd[n][0]:
            _t[n] = ymd[n][1]

    _time = '-'.join(_t)
    try:
        date = datetime.strptime(_time, '%Y-%m-%d')
        print('VALID:{} => {}'
              .format(time, date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
    except ValueError as e:
        if "day is out of range for month" in e:
            print('{} for {}, change to 01'.format(e, time))
            _t[2] = '01'
            regular_time('-'.join(_t))
        else:
            print('INVALID[{}]:{}'.format(_time, e))

for time in ['1996', '1996-18', '2019-09-31', '2019-01-31', 
             '1996-12-58', '1997-25-52', '1996-42-120']:
    regular_time(time)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> VALID:1996 => 1996-01-01
> VALID:1996-18 => 1996-01-01
> day is out of range for month for 2019-09-31, change to 01
> VALID:2019-09-01 => 2019-09-01
> VALID:2019-01-31 => 2019-01-31
> VALID:1996-12-58 => 1996-12-01
> VALID:1997-25-52 => 1997-01-01
> VALID:1996-42-120 => 1996-01-01
> ```

***Tested with Python 3.6***

Comment: Many thanks for your explicit answer ！But sorry for the implicit expression，the data I collect has several forms like **'1996' '1996-25-34' and '1996-12-45'**. I am sure you will know what I mean,I check the time one by one to ensure **every valid time is preserved**. For example, input 1996 output 1996-01-01.  But this returns an error if I put the time that list before like 1996-18.

Comment: No more agreement

Answer (score 0):

Your test case returns "1996-12-01", which is that it hits second-level "try-except", since it matches pattern of correct year and month (first failed cause day is unrealistic), then it just simplifies it to the first day of the month by adding "-01".

If you want to keep all parts of the date realistic - don't overwrite original "pattern". But fail it in first step.

Comment: thank you for your advice, but how can I fix it? It seems that I am stuck in it

Comment: The question is more - what do you want to fix there ? Do you want to fail all the wrong dates, and process the correct ones ? Or you want to e.g. treat 1996-12-58 as 1997-01-27 (so get intelligible date of 1995 years + 11 months + 58 days?